# Official Javascript MongoDB driver is slower than Python PyMongo for the same query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I've been trying out Javascript for my new backend, but I noticed something odd. When I use Python's PyMongo library, fetching all my data runs twice as fast (33.5s -> 16.44s) as when I use the official Javascript MongoDB module. The test setups are as follows:

```py
mongo = MongoClient(URI) # initializing client

rn = time() # starting timer
for ID in LIST_OF_IDS:
    results = mongo["current_day_info"][ID].find() # fetches all the documents in the collection named <ID>
    results = [[result["time"].timestamp() / 10, result["buy_price"], result["sell_price"], result["buy_volume"], result["sell_volume"], result["week_buy_amount"], result["week_sell_amount"]] for result in results] # expands list of documents into array of their values
print("mongodb", time()-rn) # ending timer
```

```js
const client = new MongoClient(URI); // initializing client

async function main() {
    await client.connect(); // connecting to client
    const database = client.db("current_day_info"); // goes to proper database

    console.time("mongodb"); // starting timer
    for (let ID of LIST_OF_IDS) {
        let results = [];
        const documents = database.collection(ID).find({}); // fetches all the documents in the collection named <ID>
        documents.forEach(item => results.push([new Date(item.time).getTime(), item.buy_price, item.sell_price, item.buy_volume, item.sell_volume, item.week_buy_amount, item.week_sell_amount])); // expands list of documents into array of their values
    }
    console.timeEnd("mongodb"); // ending timer
}

main();
```

My best guess is that PyMongo has some parts written in C, but I wouldn't think that results in such a drastic increase?

Versions:
Python 3.8.10, PyMongo 4.0.2, MongoDB version 5.0.6, MongoDB Node Driver version 4.4.1, NodeJS version 17.7.1

---

***Copied from comments below:***

Example document:

```
{
   "time":"ISODate(""2022-03-12T23:23:45.000Z"")",
   "_id":"ObjectId(""622d2b8c83d4c06e792895cb"")",
   "buy_volume":2079625,
   "sell_price":5.5,
   "sell_volume":10210328,
   "week_sell_amount":68184205,
   "week_buy_amount":10783950,
   "buy_price":7.4
}
```

Also, tried the same in MongoSH and it took significantly longer (7 minutes) I assume I messed something up there:

```
async function main() { 
    console.time("mongodb");
    for (let ID of LIST_OF_IDS) {
        let results = [];
        const collection = db[ID];
        await collection.find({}).forEach((item) => results.push([cut for charlimit]));
    }
    console.timeEnd("mongodb"); 
}
```

Comment: Despite a close request, perhaps can you show us an example document?   Also: have you tried this in straight javascript in the MongoDB shell?

Comment: Example document: `{time: ISODate("2022-03-12T23:23:45.000Z"), _id: ObjectId("622d2b8c83d4c06e792895cb"), buy_volume: 2079625, sell_price: 5.5, sell_volume: 10210328, week_sell_amount: 68184205, week_buy_amount: 10783950, buy_price: 7.4}`. Also, tried the same in MongoSH and it took significantly longer (7 minutes) I assume I messed something up there: `async function main() { console.time("mongodb");for (let ID of LIST_OF_IDS) {let results = [];const collection = db[ID];await collection.find({}).forEach((item) => results.push([cut for charlimit]));}console.timeEnd("mongodb"); }`

Comment: What is this in pymongo:
`results = mongo["current_day_info"][ID].find()`
?
In your code example, `mongo` is the client driver handle.  It next needs a database within, which might be `current_day_info`...?  But after that, it needs a collection within the database, not an ID.

Comment: Yeah, ID is the name of the collection.

Comment: Are you trying to measure performance of an application which accesses MongoDB database _or_ a specific MongoDB query as it executes on the database server?

Comment: @prasad_ I’m trying to figure out why the Javascript driver is being so much slower than the Python one, so I suppose the former

Comment: (1) You need to post the code for both the programs, with clear comments about what the code is doing. (2) Also, the versions of the Python, PyMongo, MongoDB database server, NodeJS driver and the NodeJS.

Comment: @prasad_ added to original post

Comment: Your code has various aspects to it. The query that runs on the database server, the actual code in programming language (the for-loop, for example) and the way the driver may have been configured (different drivers have different default settings). The `collection.find` method doesn''t fetch all documents from the database server - it just returns a _cursor_ (you are assuming some things), only subsequent actions on the cursor can get the documents.

Comment: The platform you are comfortable developing the application sounds preferable to me (my opinion). I don't know what you are trying is the correct approach to understand a platform's capabilities. An application is seldom designed upfront with performance as a main criteria - it should be a proper design, analysis and functionality.

Comment: @prasad_ Yes, I'm switching to Javascript no matter what, I'd just like to preserve the performance. Anyways, I ran another test, and I believe it's a deserialization issue, which I can't really fix myself. Thanks for your help anyways.